# Can you make a sheet in Google Sheets visible for certain group?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet for a timetable where about 5 people work on. 
I want only the spreadsheet owner can view and edit certain (confidential) data.
This confidential data is needed for formula's in other sheets in the spreadsheet.

What I do now is, using `IMPORTRANGE()`. With `IMPORTRANGE()`, in a separate sheet and make this invisible for other users.

What I look for is a method to make one sheet of a spreadsheet (or columns) invisible for a certain group of users.

Answer (score 0):

The best and safest way is to have your confidential data (formulae) on a **separate spreadsheet** (note: not separate sheet) and use **`IMPORTRANGE()`** to import it where it's needed to be injected. Hiding and/or protecting a sheet within the same spreadsheet is not a bullet-proof solution at all and it can be easily compromised.